# Cannot upgrade my Ubuntu installation from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I want to upgrade 18.10 to 19.04 but upgrade manager hangs and the release notes window is blank. When I click on upgrade the upgrade manager window hangs without showing any kind of output.

[image]

On terminal when I do `do-release-upgrade` I am stuck at `Checking new release` but `do-release-upgrade -c` will tell that a newer version (19.04) is available. I have tried both with root and without root privileges but still not working.

I have no more info about my problem searching on web yield no result please help me.

Comment: @Kulfy Nothing happens, the upgrade manager freezes there and I have to force stop

Comment: Are your 18.10 system up to date? Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to make sure, and fix eventual errors before continue with `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @SorenA Yes up to date

Comment: @SorenA Looks like reinstalling every package related to upgrade solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reinstalling some packages I was able to fix the problem.

Here is what I have done

1. Remove `update-manager-core` and `update-manager`

   ```
   sudo apt remove update-manager-core update-manager
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
2. Install them again

   ```
   sudo apt install update-manager-core update-manager
   ```

Then you should be able to upgrade your Ubuntu distribution using `do-release-upgrade` from terminal or the GTK tool if you prefer.

Comment: Unfortunately step `sudo do-release-upgrade` still hangs in the command line on my PC after following steps #1 and then #2.  Is there a verbose mode or some way to download the upgrade first?  And to then apply it? All `apt update` and `apt upgrade` packages have been applied and up to date.